# Show / hide element inside parent div in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to be able to display an overly of the player name and have the entire box linked to his profile. I am trying to achieve this in jQuery but haven't had much luck. The `a` tag has styling on it so it extends to `100%` of the width and height of the div.

It doesn't seem to be working - I need a second pair of eyes on as I'm probably missing something obvious.

I have this HTML structure

```
<div class="player">
 <a href="/player?PlayGuid=123">
    <div class="player__name">
        <h4>Player Name</h4>
    </div>
 </a>
 <div class="player__thumbnail">
    <img src="player.jpg" alt="player desc" />
 </div>
</div>
```

and this CSS

```
.player {
        position:  relative;
        z-index: 1;
        max-width:  250px;
        width:  250px;
        height:  250px;
        max-height:  250px;
        text-align:  center;
        cursor:  pointer;
    }

    .player a {
        display:  none;
        height:  100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        z-index: 12;
    }

    .player__name {
        position:   absolute;
        top:  0;
        left:  0;
        background-color:  rgba(44, 42, 102, 0.6);
        color:  #FFFFFF;
        width:  100%;
        height:  100%;
        z-index: 10;
    }

    .player__thumbnail {
        position:   absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width:  100%;
        height:  100%;
        z-index:  3;
    }

    .player__thumbnail img {
        width:  100%;
        max-width:  100%;
        height:  auto;
    }
```

and the jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.player').hover(
          function () {
            $(this).closest('a').show();
          }, 
          function () {
            $(this).closest('a').hide();
          }
        );
    });
```

Comment: you are hiding and showing a tag at the same time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need javascript to do that...just adjust the positioning.

```css
.player {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  max-height: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.player a {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(44, 42, 102, 0.6);
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.player:hover a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="player">
  <a href="/player?PlayGuid=123">
    <div class="player__name">
      <h4>Player Name</h4>
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="player__thumbnail">
    <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/250/250" alt="player desc" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doy! Of course - far too quick to jump to jQuery ;) thanks mate

Comment: I'm guilty of doing that myself but I do tend to reach for CSS first.

Answer (score 1):

`$.closest()` searches through an element's parents, not its children. You should probably use `$('a', this)` to select the child `<a>` element.

Answer (score 0):

**Change html to**

```
<div class="player">
   <a id="name" href="/player?PlayGuid=123">
     <div class="player__name">
       <h4>Player Name</h4>
     </div>
   </a>
  <div class="player__thumbnail">
  <img src="player.jpg" alt="player desc" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**And Javascript to**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.player').hover(function() {
    $('#name').toggle('display');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you have tried to use your code to make it work.(For some reason this works for the first time. U got to re run this)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.player').hover(
          function () {
            $(this).append($("a").html());
          }, 
          function () {         
             var ss  = $(".player__name");              
              ss.remove();
          }
        );
});
```

```css
.player {
        position:  relative;
        z-index: 1;
        max-width:  250px;
        width:  250px;
        height:  250px;
        max-height:  250px;
        text-align:  center;
        cursor:  pointer;
    }

    .player a {
        display:  none;
        height:  100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        z-index: 12;
    }

    .player__name {
        position:   absolute;
        top:  0;
        left:  0;
        background-color:  rgba(44, 42, 102, 0.6);
        color:  #FFFFFF;
        width:  100%;
        height:  100%;
        z-index: 10;
    }

    .player__thumbnail {
        position:   absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width:  100%;
        height:  100%;
        z-index:  3;
    }

    .player__thumbnail img {
        width:  100%;
        max-width:  100%;
        height:  auto;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="player">
 <a href="/player?PlayGuid=123" id="play1">
    <div class="player__name">
        <h4>Player Name</h4>
    </div>
 </a>
 <div class="player__thumbnail">
    <img src="player.jpg" alt="player desc" />
 </div>
</div>
```